# Can use data class with init{} and Gson

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, init, data-class

I have a data class

```
data class CardHistoryModel(
    val serviceType: String? = null,
    var title: String? = null
) {
    init {
        title = when (serviceType) {
            "CARD_TO_CARD" -> "CARD"
            "CARD_TO_ACCOUNT" -> "ACCOUNT"
            else -> "NON"
        }
    }
}
```

I get response from the server and with Gson And Retrofit convert to CardHistoryModel.kt

I need to fill 'title' variable with 'serverType'

when using the above code, serviceType is null

can I use init function after data parse from JSON with Gson?

Comment: Your init function will be used for every instantiation of the CardHistoryModel, what is the `serverType` or did you mean `serviceType`?

Comment: serviceType is correct when I use Gson, init is not called

Answer (score 2):

I tried some tests with Gson and appears that init is being called, but `serviceType` isn't set yet, so `when` falls on `else -> "NON"`

I don't think you can (or should) call init after your object is created, but dDepending on what you want to do, there are other alternatives...

For instance, you can create an intermediate class, something like this:

```kotlin
    data class RemoteCardHistoryModel(
        val serviceType: String? = null
    )

    data class CardHistoryModel(
        val serviceType: String? = null,
        var title: String? = null
    ) {
        constructor(remote: RemoteCardHistoryModel) : this(
            remote.serviceType,
            when (remote.serviceType) {
                "CARD_TO_CARD" -> "CARD"
                "CARD_TO_ACCOUNT" -> "ACCOUNT"
                else -> "NON"
            }
        )
    }
```

Or you can calculate title dynamically... if you **only** set title via `serviceType`, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
data class CardHistoryModel(
        val serviceType: String? = null
    ) {
        val title: String by lazy {
            when (serviceType) {
                "CARD_TO_CARD" -> "CARD"
                "CARD_TO_ACCOUNT" -> "ACCOUNT"
                else -> "NON"
            }
        }
    }
```

Or if you need the ability to change title manually after init, this should work:

```kotlin
    data class CardHistoryModel(
        val serviceType: String? = null,
        private var _title: String? = null
    ) {
        var title: String
            get() = _title ?: when (serviceType) {
                "CARD_TO_CARD" -> "CARD"
                "CARD_TO_ACCOUNT" -> "ACCOUNT"
                else -> "NON"
            }
            set(value) {
                _title = value
            }
    }
```

(the only "problem" with that last suggestion is that title will never be `null`)